# regarding query another dataframe to update a current dataframe values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

originally, I have a dataframe df_id looking like this

[image]

Then I use the following code to create another dataframe df_id_ts

```
df_id_ts = pd.DataFrame(df_id.groupby('history_date').sales.sum())
df_id_ts.rename(columns={'sales':'daily_sales'},inplace=True)
df_id_ts['history_date']=df_id_ts.index
df_id_ts['history_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_id_ts['history_date'])
```

For `df_id_ts`, I would like to add price column based on `df_id`. The thought is this, iterating over the rows of `df_id_ts`, read its history_date column, and find the corresponding price column in `df_id`, and write it back.

Here is my code, which generates the NAN value in the resulting df_id_ts dataframe, I am not sure which part gets wrong.

```
for index, row in df_id_ts.iterrows():
     tf_id_ts['price']= df_id.loc[df_id['history_date']==row['history_date']]['price']
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are `history_date` unique?

Comment: There may have multiple rows having the same history date, so I would like to compute the sum of sales for a given day.

Comment: OK, so you aggregate data. So original DataFrame `df_id` have more rows like aggregate `df_id_ts`. Then want add original `price` column to aggregate DataFrame, what is problem, because e.g. 3 first row with price want add tro first row of aggregate data (in my sample for `2014-01-06`). and it is not possible, I think need aggregate also `sales` and price. Or do you think something different?

Comment: I only want aggregate sales for one day, and the price just keep the same

Comment: OK, if check my sample data, what is expected `price` for duplicated `2014-01-06` datetime ? First value of `price` per `2014-01-06` ?

Comment: it is impossible to have different price values for the same day of 2014-1-6, it can be 23.01 for all three rows, so the df_id_ts should have price of 23.01, and sales as 484.07

Comment: OK, so my edited answer id what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) column `sales` by `sum` and `price` by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df_id)
  history_date    item_id  price  inventory   sales
0   2014-01-06  512317789  23.01      323.0  149.58 <-duplicated  history_date
1   2014-01-06  512317789  23.01      213.0  176.08 <-duplicated  history_date
2   2014-01-06  512317789  23.01      154.0  158.41 <-duplicated  history_date
3   2014-01-30  512317789  23.04      110.0  167.25
4   2014-02-18  512317789  23.05      102.0  176.08
5   2014-02-19  512317789  23.06       66.0  140.75
6   2014-02-22  512317789  23.07       80.0  140.75

df_id['history_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_id['history_date']) 

df_id_ts = df_id.groupby('history_date', as_index=False).agg({'sales' :'sum','price':'first'})
df_id_ts.rename(columns={'sales':'daily_sales'},inplace=True)
print (df_id_ts)
  history_date  daily_sales  price
0   2014-01-06       484.07  23.01
1   2014-01-30       167.25  23.04
2   2014-02-18       176.08  23.05
3   2014-02-19       140.75  23.06
4   2014-02-22       140.75  23.07
```

Solution with your code - not recommended, because slow:

```
df_id['history_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_id['history_date']) 

df_id_ts = df_id.groupby('history_date', as_index=False).sales.sum()
df_id_ts.rename(columns={'sales':'daily_sales'},inplace=True)


for index, row in df_id_ts.iterrows():
     df_id_ts.loc[index, 'price']= df_id.loc[df_id['history_date']==row['history_date'], 'price'].values[0]

print (df_id_ts)
  history_date  daily_sales  price
0   2014-01-06       484.07  23.01
1   2014-01-30       167.25  23.04
2   2014-02-18       176.08  23.05
3   2014-02-19       140.75  23.06
4   2014-02-22       140.75  23.07
```

Comment: The price means unit price, it should not be put into sum operation. In other words, the unit price is one-to-one to each day, sales is multiple-to-one to each day, so I want to compute the sum of sales and keep the price the same.

Comment: Here, it seems that you calculate the sum of price as well, how can I remove it, and keep the price column as the original one as in df_id.